# IllegalArgumentException: Invalid column null in Path of Security January of 2020

Tags: java, android, arrays, sqlite, illegalargumentexception

I came across the following code used how my projection in query of SQLiteQueryBuilder.

```
String[] selectFields = new String[5];
selectFields[0] = "pmp_id";
```

In versions of path of security of Android until 01/01/2020 (dd/MM/yyyy) this code work correctly. In version of path of 01/01/2020 the app generate the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid column null
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder.computeSingleProjectionOrThrow(SQLiteQueryBuilder.java:1142)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder.computeProjection(SQLiteQueryBuilder.java:1113)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder.buildQuery(SQLiteQueryBuilder.java:888)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder.query(SQLiteQueryBuilder.java:561)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder.query(SQLiteQueryBuilder.java:475)
```

I already fixed the error this way:

```
String[] selectFields = { "pmp_id" };
```

But i would like to understand why in old versions it works and in new ones it doesn't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`new String[5]` creates an array of five `String` references and you're only assigning to the first slot. Remaining slots stay null.

Why this started crashing after a recent update seems to be explained in [this commit](https://cs.android.com/android/_/android/platform/frameworks/base/+/0e66ea6f3221aa8ccbb78ce38fbcaa67d8ea94f9) that changes `SQLiteQueryBuilder` to be stricter with its inputs:

> This change also offers setStrictColumns() to require that all
>   untrusted column names are valid, such as those in ContentValues.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Understand!